# How to connect external camera to iPhone and take/download photos?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, camera, photos

I want to connect an external camera to an iPhone (the camera built into the iPhone is inadequate for my needs) and then write an iPhone app that allows me to send a signal to the external camera when I desire to take a picture and then immediately download the taken photo onto my iPhone so that I can send it wirelessly to a server somewhere else.

I have a lot of experience with web programming and JS, but I have no experience with iPhone apps, and I'm not sure if what I want to do is even possible. Ideally, if I could get away with coding this in JS and then using Cordova (or something similar) to make an app that can run on any iDevice or Android device, that would be great.

However, assuming that that is not possible, I would like to focus on an app for just iDevices at first. I looked around the web for resources on this subject, but I couldn't find anything.

I have two questions:

1. Is what I want to do even possible?
2. If so, can I do it by using web technologies and then something like Cordova and/or a Chrome App to convert it to something that can be used on any smart device? If not, what are some good books/resources for learning how to do this on an iPhone?

Even though I've never coded an iPhone app before, I'm more than happy to try to learn, but I need some books/resources that explain everything from the basics of how to create a "Hello, World!" iPhone app to the point that I can do all the things listed above.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have same requirement for one of my application.

Comment: I am commenting here because do not want to raise duplicate question. I want to know how to do live streaming with external camera to iPhone device and that what goes to live on Facebook. Is that possible ?

Comment: If it possible, then Apple will approve app ?

Comment: @VRAwesome that totally depends on the cam there is nothing much on app side as the first question is will your cam able to stream if yes then what medium and then only you can think about the receiver like App

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer to your first question is **Yes** But all this is not very straight forward.
Let me explain it how this can be done But I am not sure if that will be feasible solution for you.

- You can attach your external accessories to iPhone via cable
  (lighting connector now a days for iPhone 5 and later and with old 30
  pin connector earlier devices) or via Wifi (Bluetooth ). If you
  connect via cable or Bluetooth (Classic) you need to signup with
  apple for MFI . That process apple have make it difficult and now
  only companies can sign for that.
- After you signup you need to use MFI chip in your device (camera) to communicate with it .
  You can use [ExternalAccessory Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/) for your development after you done with the above.
- Another solution is Bluetooth  Low Energy (BLE) for this you don't need to signup with apple you can just enable your device with BLE and start developing your app using [CoreBluetooth framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothOverview/CoreBluetoothOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH2-SW17) . But BLE **data transfer rate is very low** so may not be good enough for photos transfer.

And answer to your 2nd question is may it is possible if you can use CoreBluetooth or ExternalAccessory Framework with Cordova or any other platform you want to use.

Comment: Imran, thanks a lot for your answer. It's reassuring to know that what I want to do is possible, and you've definitely provided me with some good guidance. I would like to ask a few follow-up questions though: 1) Can both the Core Bluetooth and External Accessory frameworks be used to both send a signal from an iPhone to a camera to take a photo and then send the photo taken by the camera back to the iPhone? 2) How can I send a photo on my iPhone to an external server? 3) What are some good books/resources for learning how to code iPhone apps from the very beginning? Thank you very much.

Comment: @HartleySan 1. Yes both can be used to send signal to camera to take the photo but for this you need firmware of camera to receive this commands and respond accordingly. After picture taken you can send photo to phone that also will be implemented on camera firmware.
2. That is very straight forward iPhone support Http, Ftp protocols you can use to upload photo.

Comment: Do you mean that I will need to (re)program the firmware on the camera or that the camera simply has to have some sort of interface available to my app so that I can do want I want to do? Also, if I can only use certain types of cameras for this task, what do I need to look for in the specs to make sure I get a compatible camera? Lastly, any good book/resource recommendations for learning how to program iPhone apps? Thanks.

Comment: Yes If the camera have api available for Bloutooth you can use that.

Comment: There lot of good books and other material but for the programer who know the languages I think this is the best to start http://www.raywenderlich.com

Comment: There are also a number of cameras including high-end SLRs that support WiFi for both remote control of the camera and image transfer.  WiFi may be a better choice than BLE if the images are large as BLE is not intended for large file transfers

Comment: @Imran Please refer my comments below question and can you please help me to sort out of this ?