# How to add external camera in iPad via USB

Tags: ios

I am try to connect USB otoscope (Like external camera) with iPad, i want to show Live video via otoscope. is this possible to connect. which framework need to use for connect otoscope.

Comment: I can't see this working as the iPad doesn't have a usb port

Answer (score -2):

It is possible but if you want to connect via lightening connector you have to signup for the MFI . There are other options also like Bluetooth (BLE and classic). How you can connect which framework you use please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32856621/1180206) .